# How to assign Set-Cookie response parameter to Secure using .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core

I am having issues assigning the `Set-Cookie` Response Header to `Secure` in my .NET Core 2.1 application.

In my `Startup.cs` I have set `CookieSecurePolicy` to `Always` within `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```

However, when I run a `cURL`, it still displays my IP & path, instead of "Secure" like so:

```
lewallen$ cURL -il https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 17:47:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=IP ADDRESS EXPOSED HERE; path=/ <-- this should be secure
Cache-control: private
```

I've also tried adding it to my `services.Configure()` as well:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; <-- Placed here
});
```

But the `Set-Cookie` header still does not display as `Secure`. What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Secure` flag indicates whether the cookie can be transmitted over `HTTP`. `CookieSecurePolicy.Always` means that it will only be transmitted when the connection is secure (`HTTPS`).

There is no built-in additional encryption for actual cookie *values*. If you are using `HTTPS` then they are encrypted by virtue of being in the header, which is itself in encrypted, at least in transit. Once on the client machine though, it exists as you sent it.

If you want to actually encrypt the value, you need to do that *before* you set the cookie, and then literally set the cookie with the pre-encrypted value. Then, when you read the cookie, you will need to decrypt it yourself as well.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Our appscan came back with a high vulnerability relating to: `Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie`. So I figured setting the `CookieSecurePolicy` to `Always` would resolve this, but it does not. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `Secure` flag is for.

Comment: And the `Secure` flag is set when using `CookieSecurePolicy.Always`? Because, with that policy set to `Always`, the `Secure` flag is not displayed on the `cURL` response (shown in question). What am I missing?

Comment: Yes. Not sure why it isn't showing. Perhaps you need to rebuild or something?

Comment: Weird. I am testing by deploying the app to our Kubernetes cluster so it should be rebuilding on each deployment. Our AppScan specialist says that Kestrel doesn't support the "Secure" flag. Kestrel isn't exactly my specialty so I can't claim if this is accurate or not